# AWS Codedeploy access a file within BeforeInstall script

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I'm bundling a file to be accessed by BeforeInstall shell script file. But shell script file cannot locate the file. I tried bundling in the same folder as script file. Still not working. It gives No such file or directory

- bundle

  - scripts

    - beforeInstall.sh
    - file.properties

May I know if this is possible...

Answer (score 0):

The files are not placed in the locations you have specified yet during the BeforeInstall step. At that point the zip has only been downloaded to a default location, so the file path in your script probably doesn't exist yet.

What do you want your script to do? Would running it during the AfterInstall step work?